# Regexp notepad++ how to put not properly

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have .txt file with 6,000,000 rows. There are 140,000 rows i want to scrape. Im using notepad++ insted of regex101 because there are too many rows to scrape. The whole document looks like that:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Sender: nick <email@gmail.com>
Message: Thats my message**

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Sender: another-nick <another-email@gmail.com>
Message: Another message

MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

Of course it's not exactly looks like that. Rows which arent "Sender" and "Message" are a little bit random. I want to extract every email which is in the row with "Sender" and every message which is under email. Of course i want to combine message with email, so i have to have Sender and his message.

For example:

```
email1 - his message
email2 - his message
email3 - his message
```

Ok, it's seems to be pretty easy, right? The problem is, that when im searching for:

```
Sender: .+ <.+>
```

it gives mi 140,000 rows

But when i search for:

```
Message: .+
```

it gives me 139,094 rows. I tried to find "broken rows" with that:

```
^(?!Sender: .+ <.+>)\r\n\Message: .+)
```

But that is not working. I think my coding skills are not good enough. I just dont know where i did mistake.

I also tried to find "good" rows with:

```
Sender: .+ <.+>\r\n\Message: .+
```

And it's working properly. But i dont know how to extract that. I add bookmarks to every found regexp and it looks like that:

http://puu.sh/nL6n4/3f6331b16b.png

And now, when i click "Search -> Bookmark -> copy bookmarked lines" i have only:

```
Sender: nick <email@gmail.com>
Sender: another-nick <another-email@gmail.com>
```

Without messages.. Im so tired of it. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: Doesn't [`^Sender:\s(.+)(?:\r?\n)Message:\s(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/oG0jG2/1) work?

Comment: Its working. I already did similar code. But i dont know how can i extract that from notepad++. When i  add bookmarks to found regexp it's adding only to row with "Sender" :/

Comment: If that is working capture it and add a dot alternative. Then replace with the first back reference.

Comment: I dont understand part "capture it and add a dot alternative". Can you explain that to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly, here is, how I would do it like this:

Open file in Notepad++ then press Ctrl+F to open search dialog and change tab to "mark". Then check "Mark line" and activate Regular expressions.

[image: Mark Dialog]

The first regular expression to search is `Sender:[^<\r\n]*<([^\r\n]*)>\r?\nMessage:\s*([^\r\n]*)`. This will bookmark all the lines starting with sender (and followed by a Message-Line).

[image: First Mark]

However this doesn't mark the Message-line, as Notepad++ doesn't support this - but we can trick a bit by doing another mark-search. Now the regular expression is `Sender:[^<\r\n]*<([^\r\n]*)>\r?\n\KMessage:\s*([^\r\n]*)`. Note the `\K` to reset the mark start. Now also the message lines are marked.

[image: Second Mark]

Go to search - bookmark - remove unmarked lines so that only your sender and message-lines are left.

[image: Remove Unmarked]
[image]

Now its time for a replace, again using regular expression `Sender:[^<\r\n]*<([^\r\n]*)>\r?\nMessage:\s*([^\r\n]*)` and replace it with `$1 - $2`.

[image: Final]

Comment: Amazing job! You are my hero! Everyting is working properly now!

Comment: @audiophonic glad it helped, please accept my answer and consider an upvote, if you like

Comment: I cant upvoting, but of course i accepted your answer :)